# ¿Por qué se hace un ajuste al hacer operaciones aritméticas en ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador, masm

Tengo un código para hacer una suma en ensamblador y funciona bien, pero no entiendo por qué hay que hacer un ajuste a los caracteres, sólo he podido observar que si no hago el ajuste al imprimir el resultado se muestra un carácter que no corresponde a un número.

Cuándo leo un carácter le resto 30H.

```
    ;read number1
    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H

    ;adjustment
    SUB AL, 30H
    MOV number1, AL
```

Después de hacer la suma se le suma 30H.

```
    ADD AL, number1

    ;Adjustment
    ADD AL, 30H
    MOV result, AL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás leyendo no es un entero, es un carácter. En ASCII, el carácter `'0'` está en la posición 48, o 30H. Así que para convertir un carácter correspondiente a un dígito decimal (caracteres entre 48 y 57) en un dígito decimal, se le resta 48.

Como te puedes imaginar, esto devuelve basura si pulsas una letra en vez de un número.

Answer (score 0):

Le sumas `0x30` porque así ajustas el valor entero para ser desplegado en la pantalla como valor caracter.